# Http 400 using resttemplate postforobject

Tags: spring-boot, ibm-mq

Below is the code which gives 400 bad request, tried various options with this but always ends up with 400 bad request, however the same works using OkHttp client

```
HttpHeaders hh = new HttpHeaders();
RestTemplate rt = new RestTemplate();
String reqBody = new ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(“test msg”);  
headers.set(“Accept”, “text/plain”);  
headers.set(“content-type”,”application/json”);  
headers.set(“authorization”, “Basic xxxxx”);  
headers.set(“ibm-mq-rest-csrf-token”,”blank”);  
HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(reqBody.toString());  
ResponseEntity<Object> result = rt.postForObject(url, request, Object.class);
```

Below code works using okhttp
[image]

Comment: Please provide source code. Do not post images of code

Comment: You have shown us the code that works? Can you show us the code that fails? Also, I would reiterate not to post images of your code. Copy and paste it into your question please.

Comment: Sorry about the pic, below is the code which is not working , getting 400 bad request

Comment: `RestTemplate rt = new RestTemplate();
  
HttpHeaders hh = new HttpHeaders();  

String reqBody = new ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(“test msg”);  
headers.set(“Accept”, “text/plain”);  
headers.set(“content-type”,”application/json”);  
headers.set(“authorization”, “Basic xxxxx”);  
headers.set(“ibm-mq-rest-csrf-token”,”blank”);  
HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(reqBody.toString());  
ResponseEntity<Object> result = rt.postForObject(url, request, Object.class);`

Comment: I agree that you should edit the question and include the working code as well.

Comment: Edited original question with non working code

Comment: Yes but you should include the "WORKING" code as well.

Comment: @JoshMc updated with working code

Comment: No way for you to copy and paste it?  Images are not supposed to be used for code.

Comment: Posting images is ridiculous.  Posting a photo of code is even worse.  Don't do either.

Comment: Updates the original post with non working code snippet, that I where I need help

Answer (score 1):

Your content does not appear to be JSON, in both cases it appears to be plain text. Therefore the header

```
Content-Type: text/plain
```

should be used rather than

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

I am unsure why this works in your OKHTTP example, unless perhaps the media type you use to build your post body somehow over-rides your `Content-Type` header?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that’s exactly my observation as well, today tried posting JSON with application/json and it worked, but not able to post string with text/plain , finally settled with using OkHttp which works well for posting string

Comment: Did you change this line. headers.set(“content-type”,”application/json”);   to use text/plain? What was the result then?

Comment: Yes I did, got 400 bad request , with Springboot RestTemplate  only application/json works for whatever reason ..